# Где можно скачать шаблон начинающему верстальщику, в котором есть PSD, и демо-демонстрация самого сайта?

Tags: html5, шаблоны, psd

Где можно скачать шаблон начинающему верстальщику, в котором есть PSD, и демо-демонстрация самого сайта? Чтобы можно было видеть всю динамику сайта, эффекты, анимацию, и при этом вёрстку делать из PSD. В источниках, что я видел, есть или демо сайта или PSD. Буду рад, если подскажите ссылку, где есть и то и другое.

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://freebiesbug.com/psd-freebies/website-template/) в бесплатных шаблонах есть возможность скачать и посмотреть демо-версию.

Comment: Спасибо Вам. Сегодня несколько раз пробовал работать с этим ресурсом, там не все шаблоны идут с демо-просмотром, а те что идут и скачиваются, потом в фотошопе все без фотографий, просто набор блоков, нормально сверстать что то сложно.

Comment: вот здесь >> http://freehtmlthemes.ru/templates/free << еще можно смотреть и скачивать бесплатно

Comment: Спасибо. Ресурс классный, современные шаблоны, есть демо, но в шаблонах нет PSD файлов. Нет возможности сверстать их правильно.

Comment: Нашёл ресурс - https://sitear.ru/material/photo-gallery-1       Не идеал конечно, но примерно то, что я искал.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/465654)